# Insert works with set but not with unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, set

In the following piece of code:

```
#include<unordered_set>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<string>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<pair<string, string> > g;
    pair<string, string> tmp;
    tmp.first="hello";
    tmp.second="world";
    g.insert(tmp);
}
```

if I change `set<pair<string, string> > g;` to `unordered_set<pair<string, string> > g;` I get the error while inserting the pair, like:

```
test1.cpp:15:14: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
  g.insert(tmp);
              ^
```

is it something on the lines of "hash function can't be defined for a pair but only for basic data types"? If I'm wrong please correct me, else elaborate it. Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard library provided `std::hash` specialization for key type `std::pair<std::string,std::string>`. Your compiler is essentially telling you that. You can certainly provide your own hash function for your key type if you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks. is there a workaround to achieve unordered_set<pair<string, string> > or unordered_map<pair<string, string>, bool>?

Comment: Several ways, one of which I see ravi posted below. That would be preferable (though the `inline` is redundant).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no standard way of computing a hash on a pair. You should provide hash function for your pair. For e.g:-

```
struct hash_pair {
    inline std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<std::string,std::string> & p) const {
        return // howsoever you want to implement.
    }
};
```

And then declare your std::unordered_set as:-

```
std::unordered_set< std::pair<std::string, std::string>,  hash_pair> mySet;
```